# How to combine 3 background images where one is stretched and two are for top and bottom?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a custom scrollbar with the ::-webkit-scrollbar* selectors, but I think the answer can also be used for any other container.

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 20px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: url('https://svgshare.com/i/bqE.svg') right 2px center no-repeat;
  background-size: 10px 100%;
  width: 15px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-image: url('https://svgshare.com/i/brF.svg'),
    url('https://svgshare.com/i/brD.svg'),
    url('https://svgshare.com/i/bqv.svg');
  background-position: right top,
    right bottom,
    right 15px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat,
    no-repeat,
    no-repeat;
  background-size: 15px 15px,
    15px 15px,
    15px 100%;
}

#scroll {
  height: 400px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

div > div {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="scroll">
<div>Inner Container</div>
</div>
```

The example is a little problematic because of the missing images. The goal is to have a top and a bottom area of 15x15px where the "top"/"bottom"-background is shown.

The problem is: The streched image in the middle need to have a 15px offset from top AND 15px from bottom. It's easy to have the top OR bottom offset, but I don't know how to get both. The middle image does have curves (comic look) and has to perfectly fit (as it's the case when using border-image*).

Is there any way to accomplish this? I also tried to solve the problem with border-image* properties, but this does not seem to work for scrollbars.

EDIT: Here is an example of the images. I don't know where to upload svg graphics for embedding.

EDIT 2: Added images. You can the the problem at the bottom of the scrollbar. The stretched, middle part, needs an offset of 15px from top and bottom.

[image: Example of the images]

Comment: try to upload the images because it's not easy to understand what you want

Comment: @TemaniAfif I've added an image of my real images. I don't know where to upload svg images.

Comment: use this: https://svgur.com/

Comment: @TemaniAfif Images are uploaded. The site is a bit weird in rendering the image. But it seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your code like below:

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 20px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: url('https://svgshare.com/i/bqE.svg') right 2px center no-repeat;
  background-size: 10px 100%;
  width: 15px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: 
    url('https://svgshare.com/i/brF.svg') top,
    url('https://svgshare.com/i/bqv.svg') center,
    url('https://svgshare.com/i/brD.svg') bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 15px,100% calc(100% - 30px);
}

#scroll {
  height: 400px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

div > div {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="scroll">
<div>Inner Container</div>
</div>
```